# How to get Pillow to make identical copies (edit EXIF in-line)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

You would think it's quite simple, but the following code doesn't work as I would expect:

```
from hashlib import md5
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("/tmp/original.jpg")
im.save("/tmp/new.jpg", quality="keep")

original = Image.open("/tmp/original.jpg")
new = Image.open("/tmp/new.jpg")

assert md5(original.tobytes()).hexdigest() == md5(new.tobytes()).hexdigest()
```

Why is it that when I'm simply saving an image as a new file, and keeping the quality settings the same, that the image data isn't identical?  What am I missing?

**Update** (Explanation):

My problem is that I have a Pillow `JpegImage` object being handed to my code as part of a pipeline and I don't have control over the step at which the file is saved to disk:

```
<magic> → <my code> → <magic that saves to disk>
```

All I want my code to do is add/update/replace (any of these) the EXIF data for the to-be-saved jpeg image.  As this info doesn't appear to be editable on an image object, the only way that I can figure to do this is to save the image to a temporary place (like `BytesIO`), save it and the re-open it with `Image.open()` before passing it to the next function in the chain.

Please tell me that there's a smarter, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure `quality='keep'` is valid? The [jpg format docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg) say that `quality` should be a number.

Comment: Well if I don't use `quality="keep"` the file size ends up being *dramatically* different.  Original: 5.9MB, new: 1.2MB.

Comment: If you are not making changes to the image file, why not just use a regular file copy via python? Every time a jpeg is run through compression no matter the quality there is always a degradation or change. Nature of algorithm. google jpeg degradation.

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to edit the exif data using `piexif`.  I don't really want to edit the image at all, just the exif info, but as far as I can tell, the only way to do that is to use `.save()`

Comment: Why not also save the exif with piexif?

Comment: Good question.  I've added an explanation to my original post.